# Why does a random generated number not work but one ive put in manually work correctly

Tags: python, random

I have created code which asks the user to type in the number version of a number from a word version from a number.

```
import random
unit = ["", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"]
teen = ["", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"]
tenth = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"]
hundreth = ["", "One Hundred", "Two Hundred", "Three Hundred", "Four Hundred", "Five Hundred", "Six Hundred", "Seven Hundred", "Eight Hundred", "Nine Hundred"]
thousandth = ["", "One Thousand", "Two Thousand", "Three Thousand", "Four Thousand", "Five Thousand", "Six Thousand", "Seven Thousand", "Eight Thousand", "Nine Thousand"]
a = 11
while a>0:
  a = a - 1
  thenumber = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
  if int(thenumber[3]) + int(thenumber[2]) > 10 or int(thenumber[3]) + int(thenumber[2]) < 20:
    teencheck = "correct"
  elif int(thenumber[3]) + int(thenumber[2]) < 11 or int(thenumber[3]) + int(thenumber[2]) > 19:
    teencheck = "wrong"
  else:
    print("not possible")
  if teencheck == "wrong":
    print(thousandth[int(thenumber[0])], hundreth[int(thenumber[1])], "and", tenth[int(thenumber[2])], unit[int(thenumber[3])])
    answer = input(print("What is this number?: "))
  else:
    print(thousandth[int(thenumber[0])], hundreth[int(thenumber[1])], "and", teen[int(thenumber[3])])
    answer = input(print("What is this number?: "))
  if answer == thenumber:
      print("Correct!")
  else:
    print("That is incorrect, unlucky")
```

whenever the number is a teen, the correct answer is still said to be wrong. If I change the `thenumber = str(random.randint(1000,9999))` to `thenumber = str(1111)` the answer 1111 is said to be right.

I don't understand why the randomly generated teen numbers are considered wrong no matter what answer I put in but if I manually enter a teen number in the code it says it's correct.

Comment: `teen_check = (10 < int(thenumber[2:4]) < 20)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @StephenRauch don't mean to sound rude but can you please explain what this does? and should it be 2:4 or 1:3 because thenumber is only 4 numbers long.

Comment: The end index is a little weird till you get used to it.  It is one past the index of where you want to end.  It is this way because it makes looping and other things MUCH easier.  Think of it this way.  The first index you want is `2`.  You want `2` characters. `2+2=4`.  :-)

Comment: @StephenRauch ahh thanks, I am very new haha :)

Comment: @StephenRauch I'm still confused how I'd implement this into my code. Can you please explain?

Comment: See my edits to your answer

Answer (score 1):

If you print out the value of `thenumber` you'll see that the number being printed to the screen in words is not always the same as the number returned from the random function. For instance, try setting the number to `3554`.

This number is not a teen, your code treats it like a teen because 5+4 < 20. I think you need an `and` rather than an `or`.

```
if int(thenumber[2] + thenumber[3]) > 10 and int(thenumber[2] + thenumber[3]) < 20:
    teencheck = "correct"
  else:
    teencheck = "wrong"
```

The same thing could be represented this way more concisely using pythons substring syntax:

```
  if int(thenumber[2:4]) > 10 and int(thenumber[2:4]) < 20:
    teencheck = "correct"
  else:
    teencheck = "wrong"
```

Which then further reduces to what Stephen Rauch suggested in the comments.

```
  if 10 < int(thenumber[2:4]) < 20:
    teencheck = "correct"
  else:
    teencheck = "wrong"
```

Comment: The summation of the separate digits is still completely wrong. Stephen's comment on the question shows a correct approach.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think through the actual logic enough, I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
unit = ["", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine"]
teen = ["", "Eleven", "Twelve", "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen", "Eighteen", "Nineteen"]
tenth = ["", "Ten", "Twenty", "Thirty", "Fourty", "Fifty", "Sixty", "Seventy", "Eighty", "Ninety"]
hundreth = ["", "One Hundred", "Two Hundred", "Three Hundred", "Four Hundred", "Five Hundred", "Six Hundred", "Seven Hundred", "Eight Hundred", "Nine Hundred"]
thousandth = ["", "One Thousand", "Two Thousand", "Three Thousand", "Four Thousand", "Five Thousand", "Six Thousand", "Seven Thousand", "Eight Thousand", "Nine Thousand"]
a = 11
while a>0:
  a = a - 1
  thenumber = str(random.randint(1000,9999))
  teen_check = (10 < int(thenumber[2:4]) < 20)
  if not teen_check:
    print(thousandth[int(thenumber[0])], hundreth[int(thenumber[1])], "and", tenth[int(thenumber[2])], unit[int(thenumber[3])])
    answer = input("What is this number?: ")
  else:
    print(thousandth[int(thenumber[0])], hundreth[int(thenumber[1])], "and", teen[int(thenumber[3])])
    answer = input("What is this number?: ")
  if answer == thenumber:
      print("Correct!")
  else:
    print("That is incorrect, unlucky")
```

Ok, this is the new code that works. Thanks for the answers :)

Comment: Oh i actually tried checking it and thought it was correct as I was lucky and  the 3rd digit was 1 everytime (I think thats why I thought it was correct :/) Thanks for the help :) This is the real answer but it's my own post so I can't say that it is :/

Comment: As an aside you can replace `input(print("What is this number?: "))` with `input("What is this number?: ")`, because `input` already prints the prompt - in fact you are probably seeing a mysterious `None` on the output, this is because `input()` is printing the returned value from `print()`, which is `None` . . .

Comment: @NeilSlater you are correct, I had no idea what the None was ty :)